# Python: Use last characters of a column to populate new values to existing columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Im trying to figure out a way to do this in python. What i'm doing is loading a CSV into a dataframe and then cleaning the data within.

```
import pandas as pd
import logging

dataframe = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\file.csv')
logging.info('Loaded CSV into Dataframe')

def clean_file():
dataframe ['Work Type'] = dataframe ['Work Type'].replace(['dual smets2'], 'EXCHG')
logging.info('Replaced dual smets2 with EXCHG')

dataframe ['Job status'] = dataframe ['Job status'].replace(['completed'], 'COMP')
logging.info('Replaced completed with COMP')
```

However what I now need to do is find out if a meter serial number ends in 2000 so i need to output the new meter model as G4SZV-2 with a FLN code! And if its ends in 1000 i need to output G4SZV-1 in the new meter model Colum with a new meter manufacturer of LPG.

I'm still quite new to python and not sure what would be the best solution for this part of the data amending! This is what my data looks like now vs what i need it to look like.
The reason why i cant replace is because the serial numbers are always different!

| New Serial Number | New Meter Model | New Meter Manufacturer | old |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G4F01236022000 | G4 (Flonidan) |  |  |
| G4F01236021000 | G4 (Flonidan) |  |  |

| New Serial Number | New Meter Model | New Meter Manufacturer | new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G4F01236022000 | G4SZV-2 | FLN |  |
| G4F01236021000 | G4SZV-1 | LPG |  |

Comment: We have no access to your ``file.csv``. Is the two row dataframe you provided be representative enough to be used as test problem?

Comment: Yeah the two rows are part of the same csv just different column as I have cleaned the rest of the csv up until this point!

Answer (score 0):

You can just `map` the last four characters of the "New Serial Number":

```
dataframe["New Meter Model"] = dataframe["New Serial Number"].str[-4:].map({"2000": "G4SZV-2", "1000": "G4SZV-1"})
dataframe["New Meter Manufacturer"] = dataframe["New Serial Number"].str[-4:].map({"2000": "FLN", "1000": "LPG"})

>>> dataframe
  New Serial Number New Meter Model New Meter Manufacturer  old
0    G4F01236022000         G4SZV-2                    FLN  NaN
1    G4F01236021000         G4SZV-1                    LPG  NaN
```

#### Edit:

To map all values in the range 1000-2999, you could do:

```
dataframe["New Meter Model"] = dataframe["New Serial Number"].str[-4:].map({str(i): f"G4SZV-{str(i)[0]}" for i in range(1000,3000)})
```

Comment: This outputs correctly! However is there away to add a range to the mapping? For instance as time goes on the last 4 strings will iterate over to 2001, 2002 etc all the way to 2999?

Comment: 2000 = G4SZV-2
2100 = G4SZV-2 
1800 = G4SZV-1
1900 = G4SZV-1

Comment: then we have other serial numbers all together which are very diffrent from one another and need to be in the same code

Comment: example "2061" = "G470"

Comment: Very unclear. You say you want to iterate 2001 to 2999 and then give values for 1800 and 1900? What exactly are you trying to do? Do you just need "G4SZV-" and the first digit of the year?

Comment: Sorry i was just giving some examples, summary 2000-2999 = G4SZV-2 1000-1999 = G4SZV-1

Comment: This works, but i just noticed a issue with this approach. 
There are other models in the data. Is it possible to map the first 4 digits in the string with the last 4 to determine the intended model? 
G4F90747971900 = G4SZV-1
G4K00000091914 = BK-G4E

Answer (score 0):

The basic concept of this approach is to use a `dict` as a lookup table for the values. Using the `apply` function, the last four digits of the serial number are referenced against the lookup, with the returned values being populated to the new column.

An advantage of this approach is that the DataFrame is only referenced once for all assignments; thus aiding in future maintenance.

```
# Lookup.
d = {'2000': ['G4SZV-2', 'FLN'],
     '1000': ['G4SZV-1', 'LPG']}

# Apply the returned values to the new columns.
df[['New Meter Model', 'New Meter Manufacturer']] = df['New Serial Number'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(d.get(x[-4:])))
```

#### Output:

```
    New Serial Number   New Meter Model     New Meter Manufacturer
0   G4F01236022000      G4SZV-2             FLN
1   G4F01236021000      G4SZV-1             LPG
```

Comment: So trying this method, i got a error "float' object is not subscriptable python" and I'm not sure why as the columns should be strings in the data frame?

Comment: Yes, all should be strings. Please check your source data. The error suggests a `New Serial Number` is blank (`NaN`), or a float value.  The subscription occurs in the lambda statement as `x[-4:]`, where `x` is the `New Serial Number` value.

Comment: oh i see, so it wont work if there are blanks in the New Serial Number? is there any way around nan's?

Comment: Of course.  Simply replace the `NaN` values with anything which is not in the lookup, '0' for instance.  For example: `df['New Serial Number'].replace(float('nan'), '0', inplace=True)`.

Comment: but does that mean in New Serial Number will output 0's instead of blanks? im not sure if that is a desired output. is there away to skip the nan's instead?

Comment: Perhaps replace with an empty string, as `''`.  Give that a go ...

Answer (score 0):

```
SN = ['G4F01236022000', 'G4F01236021000']
NewMeterModel = []
NewMeterManufacturer = []
for i in range(len(SN)):
    if SN[i][-4:len(SN[0])] == '2000':
        NewMeterModel.append('G4SZV-2')
        NewMeterManufacturer.append('FLN')
    elif SN[i][-4:len(SN[0])] == '1000':
        NewMeterModel.append('G4SZV-1')
        NewMeterManufacturer.append('LPG')

df = pd.DataFrame({'New Serial Number': SN, 'New Meter Model': NewMeterModel, 'New Meter Manufacturer': NewMeterManufacturer})
df['new'] = ['', '']
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  New Serial Number New Meter Model New Meter Manufacturer new
0    G4F01236022000         G4SZV-2                    FLN    
1    G4F01236021000         G4SZV-1                    LPG
```

-----edit-----

```
file = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
SN = []
NewMeterModel = []
NewMeterManufacturer = []
for i in range(len(file['New Serial Number'])):
    if pd.isnull(file['New Serial Number'][i]) == False:
        SN.append(file['New Serial Number'][i])
        if file['New Serial Number'][i][-4:len(file['New Serial Number'][i])] == '2000':
            NewMeterModel.append('G4SZV-2')
            NewMeterManufacturer.append('FLN')
        elif file['New Serial Number'][i][-4:len(file['New Serial Number'][i])] == '1000':
            NewMeterModel.append('G4SZV-1')
            NewMeterManufacturer.append('LPG')

df = pd.DataFrame({'New Serial Number': SN, 'New Meter Model': NewMeterModel, 'New Meter Manufacturer': NewMeterManufacturer})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  New Serial Number New Meter Model New Meter Manufacturer
0    G4F01246022000         G4SZV-2                    FLN
1    G4F01265042000         G4SZV-2                    FLN
2    G4F01253842000         G4SZV-2                    FLN
3    G4F01260462000         G4SZV-2                    FLN
```

Comment: I tired this code, and i got no output into my CSV. Also the variable SN is only calling back the 'G4F01236022000', 'G4F01236021000' but in reality there will be far more varied serial numbers. I'm not sure it this will still work?

Comment: it surely needs some adaptation if you are going to use it for your csv. How does the csv look like exactly in term of row and column? I'll try to adapt to it.

Comment: Ahh ok, here is what the whole csv looks like. This is only a test batch though so there will be a lot more instances in the future! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qBqY3XkauBVGUfzcnpE5vc8Fi21_WjBgmqgJkwbFAUo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I adapted the code as you requested to your csv file. The file is named test.csv in this case. change it according to your need. I created a new dataframe apart from the original dataframe (test.csv) and remove the empty row at the same time. Is this what you want to have or should the empty row also taken to the new dataframe?